# Entity Framework - .Include doesn't load all records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this a database with these entities:

```
public class User
{
   public GUID UserId { get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<Item> items { get; set;}
} 

public class Item
{
   public GUID ItemId { get; set;}
   public GUID ownerId { get; set;}
   public int boughtCount{ get; set;}
}
```

I need to return the list of users that have items ordered by the items bought the most.

So for example if we have this users:

```
A: userId: ..
   items: 1. itemId: .. | boughtCount: 2
          2. itemId: .. | boughtCount: 1

B: userId: ..
   items: 1. itemId: .. | boughtCount: 7

C: userId: ..
   items: 1. itemId: .. | boughtCount: 3

D: userId: ..
   items: none
```

The query needs to return the users in the following order: B,C,A (D is not returned as he doesn't have any items)

I am using the following query:

```
users = await _context.Items.OrderByDescending(c => c.BoughtCount)
                    .Join(_context.Users,
                           i => i.OwnerId,
                           u => u.Id,
                           (i, u) => new { i, u })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.i.BoughtCount)
                    .Select(x => x.u)
                    .Distinct()
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Take(take)
                    .Include(u => u.Items)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

This query returns the users in the correct order, but my problem is that for each user it returns maximum of 15 of the items he has, so if for example user A would have 30 items, I will only get his first 15.

What is this 15 items limit?

Am I doing something that cause this limit to come or it's just "hard coded" somewhere?

If so, how do I remove/change the limit?

- Note: My sql database is hosted in Azure.

**UPDATE:**
This is the generated sql query from my linq query:

```
 SELECT [I].[ItemId], [I].[ownerId], [I].[boughtCount]
  FROM [Items] AS [I]
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT [t0].*
      FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT [u].[UserId]
          FROM [Items] AS [I]
          INNER JOIN [User] AS [u] ON [c].[ownerId] = [u].[UserId]
          ORDER BY [u].[UserId]
          OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
      ) AS [t0]
  ) AS [u] ON [I].[ownerId] = [u].[UserId]
```

Thanks!

Comment: what are the values of `skip` and `take`?  I'm betting that `take` is 15.

Comment: Why would you join against Items, then use the include on the user.... what do you think join is doing?

Comment: @user1666620 the `skip` and `take` values are `0` and `10`, but they are used to filter the users not their items, `Callum Linington` i'm doing a join against the users because i need only the users that have any item, and i need the users to be returned to me ordered by the number of times their top item was bought, so the join between this table allows me to be able to sort them this way.

Comment: What is the SQL query created by the underlying IQueryable?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro how do i see the generated sql?

Comment: you can inspect the IQueryable object in the debugger, there the SQL query should be visible. Otherwise, you can cast it to an ObjectQuery and call .ToTraceString, or redirect the .Log property of your Context.Database to something you can inspect.

Comment: Hey @DevilSuichiro, i've updated my question with the generated sql, but the generated sql doesn't make any sense to me and it seem wrong, could this be a bug with the Entity Framework? or am i missing something?